# SQL query. How to Select all users whose signup_date is a Saturday or a Sunday?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

How do I select all users, whose `signup_date` is Sunday?

My attempt that doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM users
where  DAYNAME( DATE( signup_date ) )="sunday"
```

Comment: What does `SELECT DAYNAME( DATE( signup_date ) ) FROM users` show?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM users WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM signup_date) IN (0, 6)`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: why doesn't work:   sjow your error mesage

Comment: What is `signup_date` column type ?

Comment: I need to select records of people who signed up on a particular day? How do I do this?

Comment: signup_date column - date

Comment: Error:
ERROR:  function dayname(date) does not exist
LINE 43: where  DAYNAME( DATE( signup_date ) )="sunday"
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function dayname(date) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 1899

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find `dayname()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM users where extract(dow from signup_date::date) in (0,6)
```

where:
0 - Sunday
6 - Saturday

Comment: This is worked, thank you. What's (0,6) 0- first day of the week Sat and 6 - Sun? If I need to select two  days sun and sat. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific ?@LenaK .Your question is based on OR. So this answer in correct

Comment: Sorry, I meant Sat and Sunday